# Resize video in C++

Tags: video

I want to change the video size from 640x360 to 160x120 in C++. I am using borland C++ builder. I don't want to use the stretch function. Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: C++ has no idea what video is. What library are you using for handling video?

Comment: You'll need to use DirectShow API or third party library.

Answer (score -1):

See this [video upscaling example](http://wiki.avblocks.com/wiki/avblocks-programming/using-transcoder/working-video/upscale-video/) using AVBlocks. You should be able to modify it easily to do downscaling. Make sure you change the resize interpolation method to InterpolationMethod::Super as it will give better results when going down in size.